# Div não ocupando toda a altura do body

Tags: html, css, div, height

Criei uma div com width 1 e heigth 100% para ocupar toda a altura da pagina, mas por algum motivo a linha está limitada a somente 882px de altura mesmo pedindo para ocupar os 100%, só consigo modificar a altura definindo os px manualmente, mas deixando a altura inconsistente

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Home</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >    
    <link href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body class="background">
<script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="linha"></div>
```

```
html, body{ 
    height: 100vh;
}

.linha{
    background: #ffff;
    height: 100%;
    width: 1px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

na class .linha tente assim pra ver se funciona

```
.linha{
background: #ffff;
height: 100%;
width: 1px;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
margin: auto;
position:relative;
top:0;}
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).